# How to get Binary data with javascript using FileReader api with correct encoding

Tags: filereader

I got a mp4 data using FileReader api, but I have a problem at encoding!
With this function,

```
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var blob = new Blob([this.response], {type : "video/mp4"});
    reader.onload= function (evt) {
        mp4text = evt.target.result;
        mp4text = mp4text.toString()
        //mp4text = mp4text.slice(22);
        //mp4text = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(mp4text, "test");
        //mp4text = window.atob(mp4text);
        var myBlob = new Blob([evt.target.result], {type : "video/mp4"});//NOT SAME contrast to blob!
        var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
        document.getElementById('myVideo').src = downloadUrl;
    }
    reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
```

I thought myBlob has same filedata as blob but some data changed! With more detail, Many of character are same but some hex code is different. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings in JavaScript cannot represent arbitrary binary data, so doing readAs**Binary**String may not be what you think.
What readAsBinaryString does is for each source byte it gives you a destination character(I don't which character encoding it uses off the top of my head).
So if you have a utf-8 character say ✔, then readAsBinaryString will give you `â` since that character is tree bytes long `%E2%9C%94`.
If you try to turn this back to binary/blob the string `â` is treated as utf-8 which is not 3 bytes but 7(%C3%A2%C5%93%E2%80%9D)

My suggestion would be to use readAsArrayBuffer, I'm sure CryptoJS supports arraybuffers.